# ios sqlite3, the condition in where query haven't applied

Tags: ios, sqlite

```
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM voiceMemoTable WHERE folder_number = %d ORDER BY file_date, file_time DESC", [currentFolderNumber integerValue]];

    NSLog(@"query : %s", [query UTF8String]);

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
            NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)];

            VoiceMemo *currentVoiceMemo = [[VoiceMemo alloc]initWithName:fileName Path:filePath];
            [currentFolder addObject:currentVoiceMemo];
        }

        NSLog(@"### STATUS : success to get current folder %@ from database", currentFolderNumber);

        NSLog(@"current folder %@", currentFolder);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"@@@ ERROR : failed to prepare statement in getFolderFromDatabase.   ERROR CODE : %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }
```

this is the code. and,

```
2012-12-14 17:45:05.409 Rivo Recorder[9927:907] query : SELECT * FROM voiceMemoTable WHERE folder_number = 0 ORDER BY file_date, file_time DESC
2012-12-14 17:45:05.416 Rivo Recorder[9927:907] ### STATUS : success to get current folder 0 from database
2012-12-14 17:45:05.423 Rivo Recorder[9927:907] current folder (
)
```

this is the log.

I don't know why the where query does not apply. database is not wrong. it has the correct data of folder_number column had 0 value.

am I wrong about syntax of query?

Answer (score 0):

It seems ok but why don't you use some sqlite3 framework to reduce your problem? https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb is a nice choice.

Otherwise you can try to run your App on iOS simulator and access database directly.